# Restoring Amazon S3 files that are not versioned

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Unfortunately, this morning I accidentally deleted a number of images from my S3 account, and I need to restore them. I have read about versioning, however this was not enabled on the bucket at the time of deletion (I have now enabled).

Is there any way of restoring these files either manually, or via Amazon directly?

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can. Here is what AWS says in their [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/undelete-objects.html) -

> To be able to undelete a deleted object, **you must have had versioning
>   enabled** on the bucket that contains the object before the object was
>   deleted.

Comment: Thanks @abi, this is what I feared. Have contacted their support for confirmation, hopefully they can do something at their end.

Comment: @dungey_140: was aws support able to help in this case of recovery?

Comment: @dungey_140 were you able to get your files?